# Expansion in eigenbasis of the discrete Laplacian.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $
\mathbf{L}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \delta&\tau&&&&O\\
    \sigma&\delta&\tau&&&&\\
    &\sigma&\cdot&\cdot&&\\
    &&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot&\\
    &&&\cdot&\cdot&\tau\\
    O&&&&\sigma&\delta
    \end{bmatrix}
$ be the $n\times n$ discrete Laplacian matrix. This is a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix hence we know its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The $k$-th element of the $j$-th eigenvector is thus given by
$$
v_{j,k}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}}\sin\bigg(\frac{jk\pi}{n+1}\bigg)
$$
Also, $\mathbf{L}$ has $n$ distinct non-zero eigenvalues hence it is invertible and has a basis of eigenvectors.
Now I have the vector $\mathbf{f}=\begin{bmatrix}1,1,...,1\end{bmatrix}^T$. I want to expand $\mathbf{f}$ in the eigenbasis of $\mathbf{L}$, so $\mathbf{f}=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j\mathbf{v}_j$. Is there an easy trick to construct the coefficients $\alpha_j$? I was maybe thinking to exploit the orthogonality of the eigenvectors but I am not sure this is going to work.

Comment: try computing the inner product with your basis

Comment: I did, I found that $\alpha_j=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(\frac{jk\pi}{n+1})$, but I am trying to write this in a closed form such that I can more easily compare the values of $\alpha_j$, i.e. whether they get smaller or larger for bigger $j$.

Comment: try writing them as the imaginary part of a sum of exponentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems that you're ultimately looking for closed form for the expression
$$
\alpha_j=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left(\frac{jk\pi}{n+1}\right).
$$
Letting $\omega = \exp(\frac{i\pi}{n+1})$, we have
$$
\alpha_j = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{Im}[\omega^{jk}] = \operatorname{Im}\sum_{k=1}^n \omega^{jk} = 
 \operatorname{Im}\left( \omega \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (\omega^{j})^k\right)
= \operatorname{Im} \left(\omega \cdot \frac{1 - \omega^{jn}}{1 - \omega^j}\right)\\
= \operatorname{Im} \left(\frac{\omega^{j} - \omega^{j(n+1)}}{1 - \omega^j}\right)
= \operatorname{Im} \left(\frac{\omega^{j} - [\omega^{(n+1)}]^j}{1 - \omega^j}\right)
= \operatorname{Im} \frac{\omega^{j} - (-1)^j }{1 - \omega^j} 
$$
In the case that $j$ is even, this becomes
$$
\alpha_j = \operatorname{Im} \frac{\omega^{j} - 1 }{1 - \omega^j}  = -\operatorname{Im} \frac{1 - \omega^j}{1 - \omega^j} = 
-\operatorname{Im} 1 = 0.
$$
When $j$ is odd, we have
$$
\operatorname{Im} \frac{1 + \omega^{j}}{1 - \omega^j}\\
= \operatorname{Im} \frac{(1 + \omega^{j})(1 - \omega^{-j})}{(1 - \omega^j)(1 - \omega^{-j})}
= \operatorname{Im} \frac{\omega^j - \omega^{-j}}{|1 - \omega^j|^2} 
=\frac{2 \operatorname{Im}(\omega^j)}{|1 - \omega^j|^2}.
$$

We then have $\operatorname{Im}(\omega^j) = \sin(j\pi/(n+1))$ and
$$
|1 - \omega^j|^2 = [1-\cos(j\pi/(n+1))]^2 + \sin^2(j\pi/(n+1))\\
= 2 - 2\cos(j\pi/(n+1)).
$$
All together: for odd $j$,
$$
\alpha_j = \frac{\sin(j\pi/(n+1))}{1 - \cos(j\pi/(n+1))}.
$$
In fact, [we have the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) $\frac{\sin x}{1 - \cos x} = \cot(x/2)$, so the above can be written as
$$
\alpha_j = \cot\left(\frac{j\pi}{2(n+1)}\right) = \cot\left(\frac{j}{n+1}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right).
$$
Since $\cot(x)$ is decreasing on the interval $(0,\pi/2]$, we see that for odd $j$, the $\alpha_j$ decrease as $j$ increases.

Comment: Wolframalpha states $$ \sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx)=\frac{\sin(\frac{nx}{2})\sin(\frac{(n+1)x}{2
})}{\sin(x/2)}.$$ Applying this with $x=\frac{j\pi}{n+1}$ yields $$\alpha_j= \sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k\cdot \frac{j\pi}{n+1})=\frac{\sin(\frac{j\pi}{2}\frac{n}{n+1})\sin(\frac{j\pi}{2})

}{\sin(\frac{j\pi}{2}\frac{1}{n+1}
)}.
$$

Comment: I suspect that both your answer and my answer are correct; they're just different expressions for the same thing

Comment: I doubt it, my expression vanishes for even $j$ and yours doesn't

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not sure where I went wrong then

Comment: Expressions seem to agree numerically for uneven $j$.

Comment: I found my mistake, fixing it

Comment: See my latest edit.